# Growing Amulet of Mighty Fists

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, unarmed-combat

A GM recently pointed out to me the *Growing* magical weapon ability:

> Once per day, a growing weapon is able to grow by one size category, dealing damage as appropriate for its new size and allowing its wielder to affect creatures one size larger than normal with combat maneuvers limited by size. The wielder is able to use the weapon normally without penalty despite its increased size. The weapon remains at its increased size for 10 minutes.

Does this apply to an Amulet of Mighty Fists, to allow a growth in unarmed strikes? (As you may be able to tell I'm on the hunt for ways to boost my monk's damage output.)

As far as I can tell, there is no reason, RAW, for this to *not* apply. The text doesn't call out specific weapon types that cannot have this applied to it (as does Keen disallowing non-slashing weapons), and it *is* a melee weapon magical ability.

Comment: You cannot apply a weapon ability to an amulet.  If you had the Amulet and also something like enchanted fist wraps, then maybe.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Please note, it is PF question not 3.5. PF version allows exactly that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Arguing FOR:***

[PF Monk, Unarmed Strike Ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/#TOC-Unarmed-Strike)

"A monk’s unarmed strike is **treated as both a manufactured weapon and a natural weapon** for the purpose of spells and effects that enhance or improve either manufactured weapons or natural weapons."

**As [equivalent to] a natural weapon the Amulet's abilities could affect it.

As [equivalent to] a manufactured weapon Weapon Growth could affect it.**

In Pathfinder, the Amulet of Mighty Fists can specifically be used to "project" melee weapon abilities onto a weapon, so combining it with the "Growing" ability would work quite well.

---

question for thought (and a time and placed more suited to random debates): why were fists not simply declared "natural weapons", to eliminate so much of this dodging around?

Comment: To answer the question at the end: to avoid monster feats.

Comment: and yet isn't there a huge chunk of monster feats anyway? eg, "multi-weapon fighting". anyway, it was just a throwaway thought that feels like it would have eliminated a lot of problems... tho i'm sure there are at least as many problems that would have arisen.

Comment: I meant to avoid players taking monster feats.

Comment: What reason do you have to suspect that *growing* is unique among weapon special properties and might not function with an *amulet of mighty fists* the way literally every other weapon special property does? After all, it is hardly the only one to use the word “weapon” and in any case an unarmed strike is a weapon.

Comment: Isn't the ability to "project" enhancement bonuses/melee weapon special abilities onto natural weapons/unarmed attacks the one and only ability of Amulet of Mighty Fists? If not what is it used for then?

Comment: i forgot this was a PF question. yes/no. yes it -does- project other abilities, but no that isn't all it does, as it can add its own enhancement bonus to the attacks. guess i need to re-revise the "against" section.

Comment: “why were fists not simply declared "natural weapons", to eliminate so much of this dodging around?” Because despite being naturally a part of any creature, and not being manufactured in any sense, unarmed strikes *don’t* follow the rules for natural weapons (e.g. primary vs. secondary) and *do* follow the rules for manufactured weapons (e.g. iteratives). So that declaration would probably cause as many problems as it solves.

Comment: I got very confused with this discussion until I checked the edit history. Thanks for the discussion, and the words of wisdom. I will take into account, for the future, to state explicitly that my question is Pathfinder-related instead of leaving that only to my tags.

Comment: we should be checking the tags anyway; a "D&D-ish" question might be 3.x, PF, 5E, or even (more rarely) one of the many other versions. i -did- check for my initial answer, and the 2 Monk abilities (3.5/PF) were identical, and i just slipped and assumed the Amulet's abilities would also be identical without verifying.